# Spring & Hibernate, Found bit, expected TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, columnmappings

In database: there is a field whos type is TINYINT(1) and default value is 0. And in Model it is defined as TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0. However it gives error such as below:

**Error**

```
[jar:file:/C:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/NetaCommerceFrameworkAdmin/WEB-INF/lib/NetaCommerceFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/netasoft/commerce/framework/lang/dao/LangDaoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: :Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/admin-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in kaft.nc_alert_log for column alerted. Found: bit, expected: TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/admin-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in kaft.nc_alert_log for column alerted. Found: bit, expected: TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
```

**Model definition**

```
@Column(name="alerted", columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0")
private int alerted;

public int getAlerted() {
    return alerted;
}

public void setAlerted(int alerted) {
    this.alerted = alerted;
}
```

**Db.properties**

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
#hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=/import_standard.sql
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.query.factory_class=org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MySQL Settings

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoReconnect=true
jdbc.username=xxx
jdbc.password=xxx

# Property that determines which Hibernate dialect / MySQL5Dialect || MySQLDialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Dialect Versions:**

```
2013-01-17 08:45:36,920 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.0.96-community-nt
      major : 5
      minor : 0
2013-01-17 08:45:36,921 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Driver ->
       name : MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
    version : mysql-connector-java-5.1.12 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
      major : 5
      minor : 1
```

it is running on server and another computer, too. However in my computer and new computer which is installed just to try it gives same error. I am searching for days on google, couldnt figure out what caueses the issue. Tried boolean columnDefinition in model and change MySqlDialect definition however nothing change. Even error message is same.

Answer (score 6):

Use BIT as columnDefinition

This worked for me:

```
@Column(name = "my_field",columnDefinition = "BIT")
private int myField;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use tinyInt1isBit=false mysql driver parameter. i.e. jdbc:mysql://localhost?tinyInt1isBit=false

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

This prevent driver from reporting back tinyint(1) columns as java.sql.Type.BIT

However you may start getting issues with boolean fields if they are represented in the DB as tinyint(1) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add the @Type annotation to the alerted field as follows:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="true_false")
@Column(name="alerted", columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0")
private int alerted;
```